# "Ask Question" button should still be a link when asking a question

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, user-interface

Current behavior:

1. Click "Ask Question" button

   [image]
2. The "Ask a Question" page loads.
3. Attempt to click the button again
4. The button is not clickable.

   [image]

This behavior is incoherent with other buttons. For example, if you click "Users", that button is still clickable after the page loads.

I suggest removing this special behavior so that all buttons behave the same.

Opening a new question when you are already writing one may not be very usual but I just wanted to do that, and I don't understand why I shouldn't be able.

Comment: All other buttons act as a sort of homepage link for their sections. You can manipulate each page (filter / search) and click the section to return to the default page. To match functionality, clicking the Ask Question link while already on that page would simply clear all fields. Or are you instead asking for that link to remain clickable and open a new tab / window while preserving your question-in-progress?

Comment: This is almost certainly to prevent someone from accidentally navigating away from the page while writing a question.

Comment: @CubeJockey No, automatically opening links in new tabs is bad functionality. I want to be able to use right-click + open-in-new-tab, though. That is, I want that button to behave just like the other buttons. Currently it's not coherent.

Comment: @BSMP But the question is saved as a draft automatically. And attempting to unload the document should produce a warning via beforeunload event.

Comment: But the site probably wasn't saving drafts and producing warnings back in 2008 (or whenever they added the buttons). I think this should be tagged as a feature-request instead of a bug because this was almost certainly done on purpose.

Comment: @BSMP Well, I think the barrier between bugs and feature-requests can  be fuzzy. I don't care whether this is tagged with former or later.